# Unable to print the lines

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I am using my java program to print a line entered in text field using a printer it is showing a null pointer exception

My code in public int print(Graphics graphics,PageFormat pf,int pageIndex) method is

```
 public int print(Graphics graphics,PageFormat pf,PageIndex pageIndex)
{
if(pageIndex>0)
 return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
String s=tf.getText();
Graphics2D g=(Graphics2D)graphics;
g.translate(pageIndex.getImageableX(),pageIndex.getImageableY());
g.drawString(s,50,20);
return PAGE_EXISTS;

}
```

My printer job method is

```
// i have implemented Printable interface previously
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
      printer pr=new printer(); //printer is my class name
        PrinterJob pj=PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        pj.setPrintable(pr);

        if(pj.printDialog==true)
        {
           try
           {
               pj.print();
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
               System.out.print(e);
           }
        } 
     }
});
```

My UI code is

```
 JButton b; //Global variable
 JTextField tf; //Global variable
public void comp()
{
    JFrame f=new JFrame();
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     b=new JButton("print");
      tf=new JTextField(10);
      f.add(b);
      f.add(tf);
   }
```

So for this when i click on print button it is showing null pointer exception 
Please help me tomorrow is my exhibition...
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd suggest - at a minimum - posting the entire method and the entire error you're getting.

Comment: Can you post the method that uses the PrinterJob object to get the printer job

Comment: not enough information.. what is tf? What is graphics?

Comment: which line has the nullpointer exception? that is relevant info. instead of System.out.println(e) , use e.printStackTrace() to get the full stacktrace.oops only now noticed the top 4 lines contain npe, not the onlcick

Comment: It is the object of first argument of public int print() method of Graphics class .... and tf is the object of JTextField class    JTextField tf=new JTextField(10);.. for more info see the edit @sjr

Comment: Update the question and add the whole method signature.
Also add any other related code.  pasting the body of a method and leaving the relevant signature out isn't very helpful

Comment: Can you please tell me the solution @Joeblade

Comment: It can still be a number of things, based on what you posted. Run it and get the stacktrace please. it should point you to the exact line that is failing.  also, this isn't https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/Printable.html as far as I can tell, as printable interface has an int as pageIndex, not a PageIndex pageIndex.

Comment: also: pj.setPrintable(new classname());   I assume this is where you construct an inner class or something similar. probably useful if you post the actual code as this may be relevant. also post the constructor for this file)

Comment: also keep in mind: PrinterJob.getPrinterJob may return null: Returns the service (printer) for this printer job. Implementations of this class which do not support print services may return null. null will also be returned if no printers are available.  if it does, your code will fail at:  pj.setPrintable(new classname());

Comment: I have updated my full question which contains all methods except main method which contains the calling of comp(); method hope it would help you in giving answer @Joeblade

Comment: add the stacktrace and the new classname() constructor body and I think we could start helping you ;) I've listed a lot of suggestions above. should move this to chat really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have stated in the comments:

```
String s=tf.getText();
```

is the source of your nullpointer exception.

There are a number of possibilities why this is happening.
Without seeing your actual classes it is impossible to give you a definite answer.

It is possible this method gets executed before tf is assigned.
It is possible that your class is attached to a completely different instance of printer (which has tf = null).

You're leaving out important details in your question

as you're requestion an example to read text field: here you go.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class TestButton extends JFrame  {
    private JTextField textField;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField outField;

    public TestButton() {
        Dimension dimension = new Dimension(400,400);
        setSize(dimension);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.textField = new JTextField(10);
        this.button = new JButton("doStuff");
        this.outField = new JTextField(10);

        add(textField);
        add(button);
        add(outField);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                outField.setText(textField.getText());
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TestButton testButton = new TestButton();
                }
            });
     }
}
```

I think your issue is related to you creating a new instance of your printable inside your inner class. if the outer class is a printable, that means it will be constructed with new instance variables. you might need to pass **this** to it

In the above code you list:

JTextField tf; //Global variable

however if this is not a public static final , it is not a global variable. (this would not be an ideal way to expose this variable, but just saying)

**if** tf is an instance variable, then I think I see your problem.
you pass a new printer() to the pj.setPrintable method.
this new printer is a completely new / fresh instance.

**if** the class that owns the JTextField tf is printer and the owner of the printer job method, **then** you likely need to do:

```
pj.setPrintable(this);
```

**if** the class that owns the JTextField tf is a different class than the owner of the printer job method, **then** you likely need to do:

```
pj.setTextField( ... find the text field and put it in ...)
```

In the latter case you will need to create this setTextField method

My intuition tells me you are in the first category as you have a tf variable and your code compiles. What goes wrong at the moment is that you create a new printer() instance, and by doing so you create a completlely new copy with all variables set to null (comp() method sets these to non-null values, but this will not help you as they will be completely new buttons).

Hope this helps. If you had copied in a stripped version of your class file instead of copied parts of methods, this might've been much easier to find / would have meant a lot less guessing on my and other people's part.

Comment: So can you plz plz plz plz add an example code in your answer which prints the text typed by user in text field it would be really helpful plz

Comment: I'm trying to help you fix the actual problem you run into. you are supplying only small amounts of code, and only when specifically requested. I think the code you have might work, but there are a number of issues. You claim to get a nullpointer exception. This is the issue to fix as far as I can see, at least the issue that needs fixing first.    __to be able to fix this issue__ , __you need to supply the stacktrace or find based on the stacktrace, what line the nullpointer occurs at__

Comment: To do this, you might want to remove the try / catch block and check your standard output / console log, for the stacktrace.

Comment: Having said that I suspect your java process can't find your printer somehow. Put breakpoints in your code and run a debugger, it'll become clear quite fast.

Comment: Now let me tell you my problem in detail when i use g.drawString("hello java" 50,20); it gets printed but when i use some variable as String s=tf.getText(); ..... and then g.drawString(s,50,20); it shows null pointer exception ..... i have put String s=tf.getText(); in public int print() method...

Comment: ok so your tf is not initialized. this will be really helpful to put in your actual question.

Comment: When i will initialize my tf with this process and call drawString() method

Comment: I updated my answer to the best of my understanding of your situation. without the actual code / the missing parts I cannot give you a definitive answer

Comment: Thanks a lot your answer saved my project and by the way i got the answer of my question before hand when i accepted your answer